# DeleteDuplicates DeleteDuplicatesBy used in a specific situation

Tags: list-manipulation

How to use DeleteDuplicates or DeleteDuplicatesBy to delete duplicates inside list if I want to treat non-identical numbers, say $1$ and $2$ as identical?

I would define list of rules for identical numbers this way:

```
identicalrules={{1,2},{3,4},{5,7},{6,8}}
```

Meaning that I want to treat $1$ and $2$ as identical, $3$ and $4$ as identical, $5$ and $7$ as identical and $6$ and $8$ as identical.

Then I want to delete duplicates of this list:

```
li={{1,2,3},{3,5,8},{4,7,6},{2,1,3}}
```

Output should be:

```
{{1,2,3},{3,5,8}}
```

because according to my rules {2,1,3} is duplicate of {1,2,3} and {4,7,6} is duplicate of {3,5,8}.

I would like the code to be something like this:

```
DeleteDuplicates[li,identicalrules]
```

or

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[li,identicalrules]
```

I also tried a simple example where $1$ and $2$ should be treated as identical:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, # == 1 \[Or] # == 2 &]
```

But the output was:

```
{1, 3}
```

Instead of:

```
{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

which I wanted to be like it.

**Attention:** While I want to treat $1$ and $2$ as identical it does not mean I accept replacing $1$ by $2$ or vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
irules = Join[Rule @@@ identicalrules];

DeleteDuplicatesBy[li, # /. irules &]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 5, 8}}

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, # /. 2 -> 1 &]
```

> {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

Alternatively

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[x_] := x
Table[foo[i[[2]]] = i[[1]], {i, identicalrules}];

DeleteDuplicatesBy[li, foo /@ # &]
{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 5, 8}}
```

Comment: It could be without "Reverse /@" if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, you are right.